# Find out path of output file in VB6

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vb6, visual-studio-2005

Okay, I've been struggling with this for full last couple of hours. I have a `Windows 7` `32-bit` installation, on which I'm trying to compile some old code. I do not have any working knowledge of `VB`, but I'm trying to build a `VB6` project which is part of the code base. The code compiles and when I run it after `full-compile`, it runs. But I can't seem to find where this file is. Task manager shows `VB6` as process. It is not present in `%TEMP%`, and not in my project directory. Running an exhaustive search on my single drive configuration, I can find only one entry by this name, and this file has a timestamp older than current time. I attempted delete on this one while the debugger was still on `breakpoint` and it succeeded. As last resort in `prefetch` directory, I deleted that entry also, but magically this file still runs when on VB6. What must have been going on?

Comment: I figured the following additional things: 1. Make license was showing up as expired. 2. The code running might have been from a different dll altogether. 3. Something might still have been built, as if I changed the version number from properties, it would show from App.MajorVersion in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run an application within the VB6 IDE, it entirely runs within the VB6 IDE. Unlike some other languages, it isn't creating an executable file and then running it separately while hooking a debugger up, it just starts running your code using the VB interpreter.

To create a standalone .exe file, you need to create it separately. In the "File" menu, choose "Make *projectname*.exe". For full details, see "[Making and Running an Executable File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa263317%28v%3Dvs.60%29)" in the Visual Basic 6 Concepts guide.